# Dynamically duplicate category, i.e. take products from other category. Extension?

Tags: product, category, extensions

recently we decided to set-up some landingpages for specific keywords. I must say I am not a huge fan of it .. but hey let's give it a try.

Normally I would set-up a CMS Page and write some text maybe add products. But thinking about it I would really like to use (dummy) catgeory pages for it: they have a banner, text block, products etc. ..... and they don't break during upgrades. I set them to anchor = no and include in navigation = no.

**Situation:** So the only thing I miss and would like to ask: is that I do not want to manually add products to this new category. What I would want to do is to select an already *existing* category and have this category show the member products of the *existing* category (dynamically, meaning that if I add products to the *existing* category they are also added to the new landingpage category).

**Similar extensions:** I had a look at these extensions that seem to do something similar, but not quite what we are hoping for: https://github.com/tzyganu/rule-products  *and* http://amasty.com/landing-pages.html

**Question:** how can I create new categories that differ only in the way I select the products. Instead of selecting the products individually, I select an other category (ID) to take the products collection (only) from ....

many thanks, Sean

Answer (score 1):

Nice question.
Here is how I would do it.
I would add a new category attribute that is actually a dropdown with all the categories in the catalog.  Let's call it `Get products from category`.
This would establish a link between 2 categories.  You can even make it a multiselect attribute if you want in your new category to get products from multiple categories.

Then observe the events:

- `catalog_category_save_after` - When the main category is saved, check if there are other categories that use this one in the field `Get products from category` and add the products to them. Also, if the current category must take products from other categories...get them. Just make sure you don't end up in a cycle. I mean If category A should get the products from category B and category B should get the products from A. In this case you need to remember somewhere the categories involved in the same save process and don't process them twice.
- `catalog_category_delete_before` - when deleting a category check if there are categories that have a relation to it through `Get products from category` and remove from them the products from the main category. Again be careful. You might end up in a cycle.
- `catalog_product_save_after` - get the categories of the product and the old categories and check the related categories through `Get products from category` and add them or remove them from the related categories. I thing I mentioned it before...watch out for cycles.

There could be also an other approach. Instead of using observers you can have a cron that calculates the products from these "fake" categories and you can run it once a day, or when you need it.
Sorry but I don't have code for this. But from my point of view it looks like a nice idea for an extension.

Comment: ahh thanks Marius. You are always so great on answering question. I want to applaud you for it (clap clap clap. Cheer!) ... you really drive this community. (and I hope you dont mind I found an answer that involves less coding - for me -). THANKS AGAIN

Comment: And just to let you know. I was searching for an answer on Google when I found this extension (dont know why I didnt see it yesterday evening) .... and when I found it I literally *rushed* back to the question because I was expecting you to already have answered it ... ;)

Comment: @snh_nl. I can't believe I forgot about that extension. Yes it's a really nice one. I did't use it, but investigated on it a bit. I'm not sure it does exactly what you need but it's very close.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal would be a combination of

https://github.com/firegento/firegento-dynamiccategory

and

https://github.com/magento-hackathon/layered-landing